# Let $N= \langle(2,(123))\rangle \triangleleft \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus S_3$ is the factor group cyclic.

Tags: group-theory

Let $N= \langle(2,(123))\rangle  \triangleleft \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus S_3$

a) What is the order of the factor group

b) Find the order of the element $(3,(12))N$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus S_3)/N.$. Is $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus S_3/N$ cyclic?

My attempt

For the first part I know the order of the group is $24$ and I belive the order of $N$ would be the order of the lcm of its elements which would be $6$ so then the order would be $\frac{24}{6}=4$

For the second part $(3,(12))N$ I thought it would be $4$ which would be the lcm of the orders after multiplying by N. I concluded that it would not by cyclic since $S_3$ is not abelian thus the group is non abelian so its factor group would not be cyclic. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's compute the order of $(2,(1\ 2\ 3))$.

$(2,(1\ 2\ 3))^2 = (2+2,(1\ 2\ 3)^2) = (0,(1\ 3\ 2))$.

$(2, (1\ 2\ 3))^3 = (2+2+2,(1\ 2\ 3))^3 = (2,e)$.

$(2, (1\ 2\ 3))^4 = (2+2+2+2,(1\ 2\ 3)^4) = (0,(1\ 2\ 3))$.

$(2, (1\ 2\ 3))^5 = (2+2+2+2+2,(1\ 2\ 3)^5) = (2,(1\ 3\ 2))$.

$(2, (1\ 2\ 3))^6 = ((2, (1\ 2\ 3))^3)^2 = (2,e)^2 = (2+2,e^2) = (0,e)$, so $(2, (1\ 2\ 3))$ has order $6$.

So you are correct, $|N| = 6$, and thus $(\Bbb Z_4 \times S_3)/N$ has order $4$.

We now compute the order of $(3, (1\ 2))N$ in $(\Bbb Z_4 \times S_3)/N$:

$[(3, (1\ 2))N]^2 = (3, (1\ 2))^2N = (2,e)N = N$ (since $(2,e) \in N$).

Thus $(3, (1\ 2))N$ has order $2$.

To decide if $(\Bbb Z_4 \times S_3)/N$ is cyclic (we know it is abelian, since any group of order $4$ is), we compute the order of another coset. To do this, let's explicitly list the elements of $(3, (1\ 2))N$, so we don't duplicate our effort.

$(3, (1\ 2))N = \{(3, (1\ 2)),(1, (2\ 3)),(3, (1\ 3)),(1, (1\ 2)),(3, (2\ 3)),(1,(1\ 3))\}$

So we can choose $(2, (1\ 2))N$ as another distinct coset, and compute its order:

$[(2, (1\ 2)N]^2 = (2, (1\ 2))^2N = (0,e)N = N$, so it has order $2$ as well.

Thus the factor group is not cyclic, for a cyclic group of order $4$ has but one element of order $2$.

By the way, non-abelian groups *can* have cyclic factor groups, for example $S_3/A_3$ is cyclic of order $2$.